# Date Time Picker onRender method is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

i want to disable past dates in date time picker in twitter-bootstrap .for example a user can't choose a date before the present date.i write code

```
$(function() {
     var now = new Date();
     console.log('date is',now);
     $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
          language: 'en-US' ,
          onRender: function(date) {
             return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
          }
     });

     $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
          language: 'en-US' ,
          onRender: function(date) {
             return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
          }     
     });
});
```

but all dates are rendering .i write the html template code in jade engine but date picker are rendering perfectly but no date is disable i am following this tutorial

http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ .is there any method exist for like onRender in this widget as available in http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/  for a datepicker widget ??

Comment: Are you sure it is `datetimepicker` or `datepicker`?

Comment: in this tutorial it is showing about datepicker can't we implement the same for datetimepicker ??

Comment: There is no method called `datetimepicker()`.  Correct me if I was wrong.

Comment: have you try this http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#options

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
  var now=new Date();
  $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    language: 'en-US',
    startDate: now
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

It is **datepicker** not **datetimepicker**, try it like,

```
$(function() {
     var now = new Date();
     console.log('date is',now);
     $('#datetimepicker1').datepicker({
          language: 'en-US' ,
          onRender: function(date) {
             return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
          }
     });

     $('#datetimepicker2').datepicker({
          language: 'en-US' ,
          onRender: function(date) {
             return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
          }     
     });
});
```

Read this again http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/

There is no `function` like `datetimepicker` in http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AeQk6/)

Comment: apology for wrong link now please review once again the question :D